# Handle Profile Creation in a Restful Way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

i've been thinking of what is the better way of creating a profile generation functionality, RESTwise.

The idea is that my menu always has a link to a user's profile, whether it's generated or not. However, a profile has to be generated by the user at the first time and it will then be shown to them.

To illustrate, there can be a menu item pointing to '/profiles/new' and change dynamically to 'profile/:id' once the user creates the profile for the first time. This seems natural, but i don't like that i have to get a @profile instance variable in my applications controller(since it will have to be checked everytime, to dynamically generate the link).

The other idea is to have a redirection happening, probably the best of the two. The user clicks on the /profiles/new path(or an alias) and gets redirected to 'profile/:id', if they do have a profile set already.

What do you think is the best way to do it and is there another alternative i've not thought of ?

Answer (score 1):

A redirect doesn't quite make sense to me, RESTwise, as it introduces an ambiguous resource at `/profile/new`, but I don't think you necessarily need to get `@profile` every time. Assuming that `user_signed_in?` is a helper that would confirm that a user (`current_user`) is, in fact, signed in, you could create a link helper in your application helper directory that looks something like this:

```
def link_to_user_profile(html = {})

  if user_signed_in?
    @profile = current_user.profile
    link = profile_path(@profile)
    text = 'Your Profile'
  else
    link = new_profile_path
    text = 'Create a Profile'
  end

  link_to text, link, html
end
```

I'm making up variables all over the place, but hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hi there, thanx for the reply :) Actually i meant 'profiles/new', which is a standard path. However, my profiles is not about signing in or not. It's just dependent on whether a user creates one or not. The sign in process is handled in a different manner. In your example, i would need to get the profile everytime, since signing in is not really something that I would need to check for(in my case at  least)

Comment: Ah, got it. Is there a similar test that could be used to check whether a profile has been created or not, though? Maybe a flag attached to the `user` model? Either way, I'm still a little uncomfortable at the thought of having `/profiles/new` refer to _either_ a new _or_ an existing profile :^)

Comment: Yeah, that's what i don't like also, that it will have to redirect to another action. I find it a bit out of scope. But the other option is getting the profile, since i don't know of any other option to get it :/ Thanx for the idea though, +1 :)

Comment: You bet--just sorry I don't have a better answer for you on this one!

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of building a new profile `after_create` a user with default values. In this case the user will always have a default profile.